# How can i get the center point for victoria

Tags: c#, sharpmap, openstreetmap

I am following [this tutorial](http://pauldendulk.com/category/sharpmap/). But as per this tutorial the the center point is located in Netherlands. Now I need to change this for Victoria, Australia.
Could you please tell me how can i change it. Using BRutile Lib for sharpmap.

```
Transform transform = new Transform(new PointF(629816f, 6805085f), 1222.992452344f, this.Width, this.Height);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the coordinates of your center point in Google Map coordinates, and maybe a different resolution that will fit the area of your interest.

You can get the coordinates by using a GIS software like QGIS, or play around with the given values and see how the map moves towards your target.

From the first choice, you may land at coordinates about 16134321f,-4556072f.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centre_points_of_Australia in geographic coordinates: 10 km south-south-east of Bendigo, on the steps of the Mandurang Uniting Church.(36° 51' 15" South, 144° 16' 52" East)... note that 'centre' or 'centroid' differs slightly on projection.